# Azure notification hub register template xml not valid

Tags: c#, xml, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am using C#, and windows phone 8.1 in Visual Studio 2013 update 5

I am trying to get my windows phone app to register with my Azure notification hub.

If I use the `RegisterNativeAsync()` method, it registers with no problem.

If I try to use the `RegisterTemplateAsync()` method, it fails with the error;

> The bodyTemplate is not in accepted XML format. The first node of the
>   bodyTemplate should be Tile/Toast, except for raw template.

I am using a template exactly as in the example i.e.

```
var customTemplate = string.Format(@"<toast><visual><binding template=""ToastText01"">
           <text id=""1"">$(message)</text></binding></visual></toast>");
```

In the examples I have seen and the video on MSDN [[link](http://wn.com/cross_platform_notifications_using_windows_azure_notifications_hub)]
no special process is performed on the string.

I believe I need to use templates to get the cross platform notification working, so really need to crack this.

It is frustrating when things done in demos don't work when you try them yourself.

Any ideas on what I need to do to get this to work gratefully received?

I am calling the method like this;

```
var reg = await hub.RegisterTemplateAsync(e.ChannelUri.ToString(), customTemplate, @"dltemplate", tags);
```

Comment: The template looks totally fine, can you post some more code, e.g. how do you call `RegisterTemplateAsync()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So,

After more digging, and not initially believing the answer, I can say that this link contains the correct solution. [[Link]](https://andywigley.wordpress.com/tag/windows-azure-notification-hubs/)

Unbelievably, the BOM **is** preventing the notification hub methods from recognising the xml as valid.

Surely a bug that should have been picked up in testing, or at least referred to in the documentation. (Poor though it is).

Anyway, off to find the next bug/feature.